# Search, pagination, the last pages leads to 404 page

Tags: pagination, search

sorry Im new to Wordpress. I have a search list and able to browse among hits: "`http://example.com/search/SEARCHEDKEYWORD/page/11/`" I have 15 pages, and the last 3 pages leads to 404 page. So,

```
http://example.com/search/SEARCHEDKEYWORD/page/1/
http://example.com/search/SEARCHEDKEYWORD/page/2/
.
.
.
http://example.com/search/SEARCHEDKEYWORD/page/12/
```

is ok, but

```
http://example.com/search/SEARCHEDKEYWORD/page/13/
http://example.com/search/SEARCHEDKEYWORD/page/14/
http://example.com/search/SEARCHEDKEYWORD/page/15/
```

leads to 404 page. Why?

Comment: Have you check **Settings > Reading  > Blog pages show at most** ?

Comment: @PratikPatel: yea, its 10 but I dont really know what it is

Comment: In your posts listing query, how many posts allowed you **posts_per_page** ?

Comment: 8 (additionalDumpTypingSoThatSOacceptMyShortAnswer)

Comment: Try to change **10** and let me know if any query.

Comment: I set it to 1 and seems to work good, but I dont know why...

Comment: I think as its wordpress default settings so its override your query

Comment: Can you show how your pagination is being constructed? If it's creating a 404 that means there are no more results to be shown.